# How can I use srcML in Eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

[Here](http://www.srcml.org/tutorials/creating-srcml.html), in the tutorial of srcMl, they are using commands in the command line to convert the file into an xml file.

I want to make a Java program that takes a c file and converts it into an XML file

What functions should I use?

In the previous tutorial they are running some scripting commands, like `$ srcml rotate.cpp` (which translates rotate.cpp to XML).

I want a similar Java function that does the same job so that I can use it in my Java program.

I cannot find any example of that. Any help?

I hope that you understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just write Java code to fork a subprocess to run SRCML, and then read the XML produced?

Comment: thanks for your quick response
Can you provide me with a sample code please ?
code to fork a subprocess to run SRCML

Comment: Ignoring *how*, lets consider *why*.  What do you hope to do with this?  First, I suspect SRCML will not parse C code containing preprocessor directives; you might have to preprocess the C code first but that may make your final problem harder.   Secondly, you really can't do much with a parse tree.  See my essay, "life after parsing": http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Comment: Why ? I have a task I should deliver
Task description:
Given a C file, I need a list of all variables assignations, values and the locations of these assignations in a (*.csv) format. Variables here include local variables and global variables of any type.
You are required to deliver a 1 page release notes of your product as a reply to this e-mail.
As a plus task for extra credit, track pointers and their values to their actual values.

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, but this looks helpful: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/88888889-java-util/426-from-runtimeexec-to-processbuilder.html

Comment: "You have a task  (as a reply to this email)"?  This is pretty hard to do right (see the Life After Parsing page).   Where did you get this task?  "Extra credit?" This is student exercise?  **track pointers to their actual values**?  You can't do this without a SERIOUS C front end and supporting static analysis machinery.   SRCML won't come anywhere close.  Unless all you want to build is a toy.

Comment: it is a task as a phase before going to an interview to apply for a tooling job

Comment: So your potential employer wants you to build a tool as a condition for an interview?   Its clear you can't put much effort into it, and any answer you got for minimal effort would just be junk.   A "tooling company" that was serious wouldn't want junk.  This looks like outright stupidity to me.   If it were my choice, I'd look for another employer.   I'd at least send him a note saying this is a stupid request given the constraints (which may be what he is really looking for).

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and i sent an E-mail to the development team of the SrcML and they send me a demo

---

I have modified it to be applicable with any user and tested it on MS Windows 8.1 and here's the sample code

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    try
    { //this is the file which we want to get its xml representation
        String javaFileName = "C:\\Users\\Anosa\\Desktop\\tests\\BookController.java";
        //use ProcessBuilder class and give it the arguements
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("srcml", javaFileName);
        //spicify the directory of [srcml.exe]
        processBuilder.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\srcML 0.9.5\\bin"));
        //create the process
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        //let's read the output of this process[ie: the xml data]
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        int i;
        StringBuilder xmlData = new StringBuilder();
        while ((i = inputStream.read()) != -1)
        {
            xmlData.append((char) i);
        }
        System.out.println(xmlData.toString());
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I hope this works fun with you